# Python reading only some lines of a text file

Tags: python

I have text file like the following and what I would like to do it read three lines that start with 0 and three lines that start with 1 and so on until 30-40. And would like to print them on the same line. How could I accomplish this? Thank you very much!

```
0 something
0 something2
0 something3
0 something4
0 something5
0 something6
1 something
1 something2
1 something3
1 something4
1 something5
1 something6
```

Desired output:

```
0 something something2 something3
1 something something2 something3
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail? We expect your question to contain an attempt of your own, or at least some hints about where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Also, "magical numbers" are problematic. Can you articulate a reason why you want exactly three lines from the first group and three from the next? Very often, a program which implements a principle will be a lot more useful than one which has a bunch of ad-hoc limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('file.txt', mode = 'r') as f:   # opens file
    LIMIT = 3                             # change this to however many you like
    i = 0
    output = []
    while True:
        line = f.readline().strip()       # get rid of '/n' newlines
        if line == '':                    # if line is empty / end of file
            break 
        line = line.split()               # get tuple of values
        i = int(line[0])                  # get number at start
        try:
            output[i]                     # check if output has starting number
        except IndexError:
            for i in range(len(output), i + 1):
                output.append([])         # add until number reached
        if len(output[i]) < LIMIT:        # if length is smaller than limit
            output[i].append(line[1])     # add the value
for i, j in enumerate(output):
    print(i, *j)                          # print output
```